# Creating a datafreme with value_counts()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am new on python and i have a doubt. I have the following dataframe:

| country | year | seller |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 2005 | Maria |
| USA | 2005 | Maria |
| USA | 2006 | Maria |
| France | 2005 | Maria |
| France | 2006 | Maria |
| France | 2006 | Maria |
| France | 2006 | Maria |
| Russia | 2005 | Maria |
| Russia | 2005 | Maria |
| Russia | 2006 | Maria |
| Russia | 2006 | Maria |
| Russia | 2006 | Maria |

I would like to know how can i can get the following result:

| country | 2005 | 2006 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| France | 1 | 3 |
| Russia | 2 | 3 |
| USA | 2 | 1 |

I am using the following code but it is not working

`df.groupby('country')['year'].value_counts()`

Somo advice on how can i get this result?

Thank you and a nice weekend!

Comment: you need pivot `pd.crosstab(df['country'],df['year'])` good example question btw :)

Comment: add `.unstack` to your code: `df.groupby('country')['year'].value_counts().unstack()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Manakin, it worked perfectly :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @anky, it worked perfectly :)